# How to download a file and use it for import operations in php

Tags: php, oscommerce

I'm trying to automate the import of a product catalog for my ecommerce and i'm wondering if it is possible to download the file remotely and use it directly from code without first downloading it manually and then import it. This is the portion of code where the addon sets the paths, if i could just add some code to download the file and place it in the "csv_upload_folder" before the import i think it can work perfectly

```
define('CSV_IMPORT_FOLDER', 'csv_import/');
define('CSV_IMPORT_INI_FILE', CSV_IMPORT_FOLDER . 'csv_import.ini');
$config = parse_ini_file(CSV_IMPORT_INI_FILE, true);

define("CORRECT_FIELDS_COUNT", (isset($config["settings"]["correct_fields_count"]) && $config["settings"]["correct_fields_count"] == 1)); 

define('CSV_IMPORT_UPLOAD_FOLDER', CSV_IMPORT_FOLDER . $config["settings"]["csv_upload_folder"] . '/');
define('CSV_IMPORT_PHP_FILE', basename($PHP_SELF));
define('CSV_DEBUG', (isset($config["settings"]["debug"]) && $config["settings"]["debug"]));
```

This Code is part of the "easy csv import" by "cozmo"

Thank You

Comment: You should quickly add what you have tried (including a minimal coded example) or you will get downvoted. Read the rules for asking questions on this site.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous and poorly written. Also, I think you might be messing up 'upload' and 'download'.

Comment: I didn't add the code because it's not mine, the addon allows me to import a csv file from my computer but i would like to import it directly from the server.

Comment: @Mariano Even if the code isn't yours, please add it (with attribution of course). Please do not link to off-site resources for code.

Comment: I'm adding the code but I think we are moving away from the problem, beyond of the addon I would like to know how to download a file and then use it in a script without downloading it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it, i used `file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen("http://someurl/file.zip", 'r'));` to download the file in the same dir of the script